# Как разместить компоненты не залезая за границы экрана

Tags: java, android

Есть *RelativeLayout* . 
В нем я размещаю несколько ImageView , делаю я это в Graphical Layout (eclipse).

И иногда получается что изображение уходит в низ, и видно только на половину.
Я конечно понимаю что можно это исправить просто перетащив ImageView чуть выше, но если экран будет еще меньше - оно все равно выйдет за границы.

Так вот, как мне не позволить компонентам ImageView не уходить за границы экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не использовать `Graphical Layout`, делать всё в `xml`.
2. В `xml` поиграться в атрибутами `height`, `width`, `weight`и `scaleType` так, чтобы `ImageView` не вылезали за пределы экрана.